# SVN revision numbers for multiple file commits

Tags: svn, version-control

Is there any way that when a developer commits multiple files (suppose 5 files), only a single revision is generated?

Or does each file commit, no matter how it is committed, always cause a new revision number to be generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the files are committed all at once, there is only one revision generated.

Example `svn log` output:

```
r41614 | blorg | 2013-08-29 15:16:49 +1200 (Thu, 29 Aug 2013) | 2 lines
Changed paths:
   M /customers/Footech/PricingDatabaseLoader.cs
   M /customers/Footech/CreditRecharge.cs
   M /customers/Footech/build.cfg
```

Here we have a single revision (r41614) in which 3 files were committed.

Comment: So, if in Eclipse, I select a whole project and commit the project, even if it has 1000 modified files, then only one revision number will be generated for all 1000 files committed?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Every separate commit gets a unique revision number; but there can be many changes in each commit.

Answer (score 1):

If you commit multiple files together there will be a single revision number for all the files. i.e. it is a single change set commit that has multiple files